# The splice method causes the for loop to be executed n - 2 times (n is the number of elements in an array)

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the elements of an array with n elements using a for loop and the splice method one by one. The loop is executed n - 2 times and there will be 2 elements inside the array at the end. Why is that so?

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach']

for(index in fruits){
    console.log('Execution Number:', index);
    console.log('Before:', fruits);
    fruits.splice(0, 1);
    console.log('After:', fruits);
    console.log('-'.repeat(50));
}

console.log('\nFinal Result:', fruits)
```

result:

```
Execution Number: 0
Before: [ 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach' ]
After: [ 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach' ]
--------------------------------------------------
Execution Number: 1
Before: [ 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach' ]
After: [ 'Watermelon', 'Peach' ]
--------------------------------------------------

Final Result: [ 'Watermelon', 'Peach' ]
```

I know that I can do this with a single line of code using the splice method but I wanted to test if I can do this using a for loop.

Comment: use this fruits.splice(0); instead of fruits.splice(0, 1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen because you are reducing the length of the array in every loop. By doing this, the number of element in the array decrease but the index still increment.

| Fruits | Index |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach'] | 0 | `0 < 4` so, Apple is deleted |
| ['Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach'] | 1 | `1 < 3` so, Orange is deleted |
| ['Watermelon', 'Peach'] | 2 | `2 < 2` **Here `2 < 2` is false, the loop stops** |

A solution would be to do a for loop with a fixed length calculated before the loop

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach']
const length = fruits.length
for (let index = 0; index < length; index++){
    console.log('Execution Number:', index);
    console.log('Before:', fruits);
    fruits.splice(0, 1);
    console.log('After:', fruits);
    console.log('-'.repeat(50));
}

console.log('\nFinal Result:', fruits)
```

As @reyno was mentioning, in the above snippets you can't access fruits individually.
In fact if you want to access each fruit in the foor loop you can do this by accessing to the first element of the array each time : `fruits[0]`

Comment: Sidenote: Though this works you still cant access individual items like `fruits[index]` since it will return undefined for the last 2 iterations. Then again that isn't specified in OP's question anyway.

Comment: @Reyno it would return `undefined` if he was doing someting like the `findIndex` method. But here he is only doing splice and he wants to do it n times . There is no undefined variables

Answer (score 2):

The issue is being seen because the length of the array is decreased by one in each iteration due to `fruits.splice(0,1)`.

1. Iteration 1 - index = 0; `fruits.length` = 4
2. Iteration 2 - index = 1; `fruits.length` = 3
3. Iteration 3 - index = 2; `fruits.length` = 2 -> `for loop breaks`

Hence, the observation.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `fruits.splice` you are modifying the array used for the for loop itself. If you look at `index`, it is incrementing in each loop. After `Execution Number: 1`, it increments to 2 and looks at `fruits` and sees there is no more elements. Seeing that, it exits the for loop.

If you want to do it with a for loop, what you probably wanted was

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach']

const fruitsLen = fruits.length;
for(let i = 0; i < fruitsLen; i++){
    console.log('Execution Number:', i);
    console.log('Before:', fruits);
    fruits.splice(0, 1);
    console.log('After:', fruits);
    console.log('-'.repeat(50));
}

console.log('\nFinal Result:', fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Splice mutates the original array, implying that the length of array decreases each time you do `fruits.splice(0,1)`, hence, after 2 turns, there are not more `items` in the array to traverse, hence the loop breaks.

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Peach']

for(index in fruits){
    console.log('Execution Number:', index);
    console.log('Before:', fruits);
    fruits.splice(0, 1);
    console.log('After:', fruits, fruits.length); // Goes from 3 to 2 and then exits after 2 turns 
    console.log('-'.repeat(50));
}

console.log('\nFinal Result:', fruits)
```

More details on splice : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice